# firebird: computing with date

Tags: firebird

I have `SELECT` statement from 3 tables. Need help in one `WHERE` condition. E.g. in first table date field sets date as `2014-02-26`, in the second - random integer 7, 14 or 30. So i have something like this `SELECT ... JOIN ... WHERE (first_table.date + second_table.integer - NOW) = 1`. `SELECT` and `JOIN` part I know. I need some help with date computing.

Comment: [`DATEADD`](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-intfunc-dateadd.html) and [`DATEDIFF`](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-intfunc-datediff.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
SELECT ... 
FROM ... 
JOIN ... 
WHERE (DATEDIFF(DAY FROM first_table.date TO NOW) + second_table.integer) = 1
```